# WCF webservice over basicHttpBinding with Streaming uses over 2 gigs of ram

Tags: c#, wcf, memory

I have an IIS hosted WCF webservice, it has two endpoints, one for wsHttpBinding, the other is for basicHttpBinding.  I use basicHttpBinding so I can set the transferMode to "Streamed" so I can stream files.  This service also is under SSL and needs a client certificate to connect to.

When I call the wsHttpBinding services and everything is fine.  When I call the basicHttpBinding services to stream a file it will use all the free ram (the machine has 2.5 gigs) and then hits the page file and throws hard faults.  All these hard faults and disk swapping causes the services to time out since it's taking longer than 60 seconds to return.

Below is the function that I am calling that is eating all the ram and timing out

```
[OperationBehavior]
public Stream GetOrderResults(string clientName, string userName, string password, string institutionId, Guid orderId, string fileName)
{
var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"\\iwebdev510\Relateprod\TDHub\Temp\TDTestClient\bob.xml", FileMode.Open);
return fileStream;
}
```

The configuration file for the client calling the webservice looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- REMOVE THE BEHAVIORS FOR DEV TESTING -->
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientCertBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="8b08c6e6e356a345212e539979fbcaca337aae8a"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <client>
      <!--Dev Endpoints With Certs-->
      <endpoint address="https://<obfuscated>/secure/TDHubService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertBehavior"
        binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="wsTDHubServiceBindingTLS"
        contract="MortgageCadence.External.TDHub.Protocols.Contracts.Services.ITDHubService" />
      <endpoint address="https://<obfuscated>/secure/TDHubFileTransferService.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertBehavior"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="basicTDHubFileTransferServiceBindingTLS"
        contract="MortgageCadence.External.TDHub.Protocols.Contracts.Services.ITDHubFileTransferService" />

    </client>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicTDHubFileTransferServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="basicTDHubFileTransferServiceBindingTLS" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsTDHubServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="wsTDHubServiceBindingTLS" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can provide a screen shot of the computers resource monitor being eaten by w3wp.exe, but I can't attach it ATM because my reputation is not high enough.

I have discovered that if I change the transfer mode from "Steamed" to "Buffered" in the binding it completely solves the memory issue, but this appears to be counter to what the documentation suggests.  The documentation makes it sound like if you choose "buffered" it will load the entire file into memory before sending, but I've sent a 700 meg file and the memory didn't change in buffered mode.

Comment: Why do you set those `readerQuotas` values?

Comment: Our requirements are not fully set, so until we get the final "max file sizes for download" we just maxed it out.  Can the readerQuotas impact the amount of ram a webservice can use?

Comment: I have never adjusted them from the defaults so I don't know. I just had never seen them set before so it stuck out to me so I was wondering why.

Comment: What's the file size you are transfering?

Comment: I am currently transferring a 1KB file (an XML file with just an empty tag in it), but the system could be asked to transfer files up to 50 megabytes in size or larger.

Comment: How did you measure the "2 Gig of ram"? Task Manager?

Comment: Yes, Task Manager and Resource Monitor on the machine, watching the w3wp.exe process.